# NEC fire pump question

Tags: power-supply, motor

The fire pump nameplate voltage is 460 V, however, the transformer supplying the pump has a voltage of 480 V **at the motor terminals**.

Should the Locked Rotor Current LRC for the pump be calculated based on the motor terminal voltage i.e. 480 V, or should the calculation of the LRC be as per the motor nameplate?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right place for this question. BUT, I think I would look into the details of the transformer a little more. If the secondary is rated at 480, that is not the same as saying that it will deliver 480. Maybe the primary voltage is below rating, thus causing the output voltage to be below rating. So I think I would look into all those details.

Comment: 480 is a common number for the high side of tolerance of what comes through the power line but, 460 is the specified "typical" or target voltage.  Just like many people talk about 220 or 240v but actual specification across Europe is 230VAC +10%/−6%.

Comment: Locked rotor current derives from resistive losses in winding so to be 100% exact you should use 480. However there are *wide* tolerances (up to 20%, both for supply and for the motor) so it's more of a *typical* value. You'll see that the value is not that different anyway

Answer (score 0):

The LRC motor plate current is the motor current measured in the factory at 460 V.

If you connect to a 480 V supply you should recalculate the LRC current as :
RLCn = RLCo x 460/480